# how to control what the text in a textfield looks like

Tags: ios, xcode4, uitextfield

I am writing an iPhone program that involves passwords, and I want to know how to make the textfield print dots or stars or something else when you type, instead of what you are typing. How do i do that? I have xcode 4 and i am running mac osx 10.6.8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this

```
[textField setSecureTextEntry:YES];
```